# Android: TextView word-wrap with shortest line first

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, word-wrap

For a graphical banner I am having two `TextView`s positioned on top of each other.

The top `TextView` is aligned to bottom and the bottom one is aligned to top so that the texts are always positioned around the same center. The `TextViews` look like this in the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="126dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:gravity="bottom|left"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:textColor="#AAAAAA"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that when the top `TextView` wraps the text, the wrapping is with the last line as the smallest one, and not taking into account that I am aligning to the bottom. See below.

[image: banner example]

I would have expected the gravity, to make the text wrapping happen in a way that has most of the text on the bottom line.

Any suggestions to how I could get the `TextView` to perform the word-wrapping in a last-line-first mannor?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I don't understand the expected behavior vs the shown behavior. can you please show it in pictures what's wrong here?

Comment: I think this is not possible in android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no last-line-first mannor as you need, however, there are some suggestion I would like to give:

**Solution 1**: Let your text view (top one) be the single-line and with the ellipsize. This way, you will ensure your text view alway at the bottom of the container with a single line and ... at the end of the text. The drawback, the text may not displayed fully.

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

**Solution 2:** You need to calculate the size of each character of your text, split your top text view into 2 text views, assign the text for those 2 text views. For example, in your case. After calculating the size of your text and compare with the size of the text view (the width in this case) , you will assign "The 20/20" to the top-top one, and the remain "Experience - 2 of 2 (Deluxe)" to top-bottom one. This can also apply to the long text with more than 2 lines. Just calculate and apply correctly, it will work. Here is the code for calculate the text size in pixel:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
        String your_text = "This is your text";
        float size = p.measureText(your_text);
        // assign one part to the top-top
        // assign another part to the top-bottom
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="First TextView"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:text="Second TextView"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```